# What is the log of the PDF for a Normal Distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, likelihood, logarithm

I am learning Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

Per [this post](https://medium.com/@rrfd/what-is-maximum-likelihood-estimation-examples-in-python-791153818030), the log of the PDF for a normal distribution looks like this:

$$
\log{\left(f\left(x_i;\,\mu,\sigma^2\right)\right)}
=
- \frac{n}{2} \log{\left(2 \pi\right)}
- \frac{n}{2} \log{\left(\sigma^2\right)}
- \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum{{\left(x_i - \mu\right)}^2}
\tag{1}
$$

According to any Probability Theory textbook, the formula of the PDF for a normal distribution:
$$
\frac {1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}
e^{-\frac {(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}
\rlap{\qquad \text{where}~-\infty <x<\infty}
\tag{2}
$$

Taking the log of Expression 2 produces

\begin{align}
\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}
e^{-\frac{\left(x - \mu\right)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}\right) &= 
\ln\left(\frac {1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}\right)+\ln{\left(e^{-\frac {(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}\right)} \tag{3} \\[5px]
&=-\ln\left(\sigma\right)-\frac{1}{2} \ln\left(2\pi\right) - \frac{\left(x - \mu\right)^2}{2\sigma ^2} \tag{4}
\end{align}

which is very different from Equation 1.

Is Equation 1 right?  What am I missing?

Comment: Your first equation is the *joint* log-pdf of a sample of n iid normal random variables (AKA the log-likelihood of that sample). The second equation is the the log-pdf of a single normal random variable

Comment: @ArtemMavrin, I think your comment would be a perfectly good answer if you expanded on just a bit to make it slightly more clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a single observed value $x$ you have log-likelihood:

$$\ell_x(\mu,\sigma^2) = - \ln \sigma - \frac{1}{2} \ln (2 \pi) - \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \Big)^2.$$

For a *sample* of IID observed values $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_n)$ you then have:

$$\ell_\mathbf{x}(\mu,\sigma^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ell_{x_i}(\mu,\sigma^2) = - n \ln \sigma - \frac{n}{2} \ln (2 \pi) - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu)^2.$$

(Note that in both cases you can remove the constant term from the log-likelihood, but then it is not the logarithm of the sampling density.)